# Disable the natural sort order in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How to disable the natural sort order Windows Explorer?

Example (left is natural sort order, right is the usual sort, i.e. lexicographical order):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Save as a `.reg` the following code, execute it, and restart `explorer.exe`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;Created by Vishal Gupta for AskVG.com
;Windows XP, Vista and 7
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoStrCmpLogical"=dword:00000001
```

To restore the natural sort order: save as a `.reg` the following code, execute it, and restart `explorer.exe`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00    
;Created by Vishal Gupta for AskVG.com
;Windows XP, Vista and 7
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoStrCmpLogical"=-
```